# Tidy pls summary results

Tags: r

Using the data.frame df and `pls`, I got the summary
using

```
library(pls)
Y <- as.matrix(df[,14])
X <- as.matrix(df[,1:11])
df.pls <- mvr(Y ~ X, ncomp = 5, method = "oscorespls", scale = T)
summary(df.pls)

Data:   X dimension: 20 11 
    Y dimension: 20 1
Fit method: oscorespls
Number of components considered: 5
TRAINING: % variance explained
   1 comps  2 comps  3 comps  4 comps  5 comps
X    34.86    72.01    81.01    85.04    90.95
Y    42.12    47.72    59.76    73.74    77.52
```

Any suggestions how to get the summary(df.pls) in a tidy data.frame?

**Data**

(Source: http://eric.univ-lyon2.fr/~ricco/tanagra/fichiers/en_Tanagra_PLSR_Software_Comparison.pdf)

```
df <- read.table(text = c("
diesel  twodoors    sportsstyle wheelbase   length  width   height  curbweight  enginesize  horsepower  horse_per_weight    conscity    price   symboling
0   1   0   97  172 66  56  2209    109 85  0.0385  8.7 7975    2
0   0   0   100 177 66  54  2337    109 102 0.0436  9.8 13950   2
0   0   0   116 203 72  57  3740    234 155 0.0414  14.7    34184   -1
0   1   1   103 184 68  52  3016    171 161 0.0534  12.4    15998   3
0   0   0   101 177 65  54  2765    164 121 0.0438  11.2    21105   0
0   1   0   90  169 65  52  2756    194 207 0.0751  13.8    34028   3
1   0   0   105 175 66  54  2700    134 72  0.0267  7.6 18344   0
0   0   0   108 187 68  57  3020    120 97  0.0321  12.4    11900   0
0   0   1   94  157 64  51  1967    90  68  0.0346  7.6 6229    1
0   1   0   95  169 64  53  2265    98  112 0.0494  9.0 9298    1
1   0   0   96  166 64  53  2275    110 56  0.0246  6.9 7898    0
0   1   0   100 177 66  53  2507    136 110 0.0439  12.4    15250   2
0   1   1   94  157 64  51  1876    90  68  0.0362  6.4 5572    1
0   0   0   95  170 64  54  2024    97  69  0.0341  7.6 7349    1
0   1   1   95  171 66  52  2823    152 154 0.0546  12.4    16500   1
0   0   0   103 175 65  60  2535    122 88  0.0347  9.8 8921    -1
0   0   0   113 200 70  53  4066    258 176 0.0433  15.7    32250   0
0   0   0   95  165 64  55  1938    97  69  0.0356  7.6 6849    1
1   0   0   97  172 66  56  2319    97  68  0.0293  6.4 9495    2
0   0   0   97  172 66  56  2275    109 85  0.0374  8.7 8495    2"), header = T)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `broom` package?